# How to find dual of optimization problem and prove if it is feasible or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, duality-theorems, semidefinite-programming

Given $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, I want to find out if the dual of the following problem is always solvable:

\begin{array}{ll} \underset{X\in\mathbb{C^{n\times n}}}{\text{minimize}} & \mathrm{trace}\big((A+A^*)X).\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm{trace}(A^*AX)=1,\\&\mathrm{trace}(X)=1,\\&X\geq0.\end{array}

---

$L(X,\lambda_1,\lambda_2)=\mathrm{trace}\big((A+A^*)X)-\lambda_1(\mathrm{trace}(A^*AX)-1)-\lambda_2(\mathrm{trace}(X)-1)$, then

\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial L(X,\lambda_1,\lambda_2)}{\partial X}=(A+A^*)-\lambda_1A^*A-\lambda_2I,
\end{align}

and the corresponding dual problem is

\begin{array}{ll} \underset{\lambda_1,\lambda_2}{\text{maximize}} & \lambda_1+\lambda_2.\\ \text{subject to} & (A+A^*)-\lambda_1A^*A-\lambda_2I\succeq0.\end{array}

I am not sure if this is correct dual problem and how to show that it is not always solvable (i.e. not always feasible).

Comment: The dual looks correct to me except that I don't immediately see why $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are nonnegative. To see the primal isn't always feasible try taking $A = c I$ and choose $c\in \mathbb{R}$ in order to break the consistency of the constraints,

Comment: I thought we need to make $\lambda_i'$s always nonnegative, they can be any real?

Comment: No, you don't need to. I think with $\lambda_i$ nonnegative it corresponds to the dual of the primal problem where you replace your equality constraints with $\geq$. You may be able to show that these two problems are equivalent, however, I have not checked this.

Comment: thanks, I have edited the question